# How to dynamically update directive once user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have an app with a navbar directive and basic sign up/log in functionality. I want to change some of the words on the nav bar (from 'signup/login' to 'sign out') once the user is logged in, but I can't figure out the best (or even one) way to do this. I've tried setting the value of the variable/binding I want to change to a factory that gets updated when the user logs in, but this doesn't work, and the directive doesn't update with its new value.

My code is attached below, specific solutions are appreciated but not really necessary, if anyone can just point me in the right direction with how to do this that would be very helpful.

Solutions I've tried:

- Factories

  1. setting binding variables equal to factory variables that are updated
  2. setting binding variables equal to the output of getter statements for those variables
- Cookies (would prefer to avoid unless someone convinces me it's a good way of solving this)

  3. setting binding variables equal to values in cookies

Unfortunately none of these cause the directive variable to dynamically update as well. I feel like the solution is very simple but I can't think of what I should be doing.

Potential Solutions:

- using routing, e.g. changing the view from one navbar to another when the user is logged in, although this seems really clunky
- $rootScope (not entirely sure how to use this and I'm guessing it's the wrong use for this anyway)

navbar.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Home
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="message">Message</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="list">User List</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="schedule">Schedule</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a ng-href="{{ vm.accountStatusLink }}">{{ vm.accountStatus }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

navbar.directive.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('mainNavbar', mainNavbar);

  mainNavbar.$inject = ['userFactory'];

  function mainNavbar(userFactory) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar/navbar.html',
      scope: {
          creationDate: '='
      },
      controller: NavbarController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;


    function NavbarController() {
      var vm = this;
      // solution 1 (doesn't work)
      vm.accountStatus = userFactory.userStatus;
      vm.accountStatusLink = userFactory.userStatusLink;
      // solution 2 (doesn't work)
      //vm.accountStatus = userFactory.getUserStatus();
      //vm.accountStatusLink = userFactory.getUserStatusLink();
    }
  }

})();
```

user.factory.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('userFactory', userFactory);

  userFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies'];

  function userFactory($http, $cookies) {
    var userStatusLink = '#/user/';
    var userStatus = 'Sign Up / Log In';
    var service = {
      verifyUser: verifyUser,
      storeUser: storeUser,
      userStatusLink: userStatusLink,
      userStatus: userStatus
    };
    return service;

    /* verifyUser() snip */

    function storeUser(user) {
      $cookies.putObject('user', user); // stores user obj in cookies
      userStatusLink = '#/signout/';
      userStatus = 'Sign Out';
    }

    /* solution 2 getters

    function getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }

    function getUserStatusLink() {
        return userStatusLink;
    }

    */

  }

})();
```

**Update:**

`userFactory.storeUser(user)` is happening asynchronously inside of a `.success` callback:

```
$http.post('someurl').success(function(user) {
    userFactory.storeUser(user);
});
```

Comment: You can try using ng-show and ng-hide - http://embed.plnkr.co/AdyiSQB1qbsF98l6TUmz/preview

Comment: That would be a great solution but I don't have a way of getting the 'logged in' boolean to the directive, as the logic that handles the log-in is in a different controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making a getUserStatusLink and a getUserStatus method, and binding your view to those methods instead?

```
function userFactory($http, $cookies) {
  ...
  var service = {
    ...
    getUserStatusLink: function() {
      return userStatusLink;
    },
    getUserStatus:  function() {
      return userStatus;
    }
  };
  ...
}
```

And then in your NavBar controller:

```
function NavbarController() {
  ...
  vm.accountStatusLink = userFactory.getUserStatusLink();
  vm.accountStatus = userFactory.getUserStatus();
}
```

This should do what you are looking for it to do when userStatusLink and userStatus are updated in your userFactory.

**Update:**

Since your `storeUser()` method is being called asynchronously, it is not triggering another digest cycle to happen when your new values are set. So you should force Angular to perform a digest cycle using the $timeout service:

```
userFactory.$inject = [ ..., '$timeout'];

function userFactory( ..., $timeout) {
  ...
  function storeUser(user) {
    ...
    // forces Angular to perform a digest cycle, thus refreshing your view
    $timeout(function() {
      userStatusLink = '#/signout/';
      userStatus = 'Sign Out';
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

**Update 2:**

Working jsFiddle with this implementation. I included two methods so you can see the difference in using $timeout and not using $timeout: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15366/

I steered you wrong in one place, update your controller variables to access the method directly like so:

```
function NavbarController() {
  ...
  // remove the parens at the end of userFactory.getUserStatusLink();
  vm.accountStatusLink = userFactory.getUserStatusLink;
  // remove the parens at the end of userFactory.getUserStatus();
  vm.accountStatus = userFactory.getUserStatus;
}
```

And then update your view to actually call the methods:

```
<!-- add parens to view to make it actually call the methods -->
<li><a ng-href="{{ vm.accountStatusLink() }}">{{ vm.accountStatus() }}</a></li>
```

**Final Update:**

Turns out $timeout was unnecessary, since Angular performs a digest cycle in the success callback of the $http service. Simply updating the view to access the method directly was enough to fix it.

Comment: This is actually what I tried doing in solution 2, it appears to have the same result as simply setting the Navbar's variables to the Factory's variables directly (as I have it now).

Comment: Is storeUser being called asynchronously? Maybe you should try wrapping where you set userStatusLink and userStatus in a $timeout method so that it forces Angular to run a digest cycle after you have set those variables. Example: $timeout(function() { userStatusLink = 'blah'; userStatus = 'blah'; });

Comment: So storeUser() is called within a .success callback, would this be considered as being called asynchronously? (Sorry, bit new to promises and that)

Comment: Yeah, that means it is being called asynchronously, which means it is outside of Angular's digest cycle. So in order to force Angular to perform another digest cycle after you set the new values, simply set them within a `$timeout` method. I will update my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Ah, this didn't work, unfortunately :( thought you'd figured it out! I feel like I'm just approaching this whole thing incorrectly and there should be a much easier/less complex way to do this. I think I'm going to try out the $rootScope.$emit solution offered below.

Comment: So, I can assure you that this does work, I have updated the answer to include a working jsFiddle and I think I had one thing wrong in the implementation details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83571/discussion-between-kanzelm3-and-turner).

Answer (score 1):

First off the display values of login and logout should be within the directive. That widget (directive) should be what owns all of the presentation of the login / logout.

This sounds like you are really trying to communicate between directives. Which is a common thing for people to get stuck on. You could expose the user values in the factory and have the directive watch for changes but that is expensive as it uses up 1 of the finite number of watches.

The common pattern to communicate data between directives is to use events. Your factory or another directive could `$rootScope.$emit('user-signed-in', userData)`.

This emits an event on the $rootScope and all parent scopes, but there are none so it quicker then a $broadcast.

Your directive then listens for the event `$rootScope.on('user-signed-in', function(userData) {})`.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a complicated/convoluted solution to this, is this really the best way of doing it? I feel like there should be a simpler way to pass the information around. I'm not trying to communicate between directives per se, but just between a factory and a directive.

Comment: Without using events the only other thing you can do it expose a `getUser` method on the factory and within the directive do a `$watch` on that functions, if a user is returned then they are logged in. This does mean that you will be checking if a user exists on every angular lifecycle, which is very frequently.

Comment: Why a complicated solution? It's extremely simple. Did you even try it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to duplicate your links and use ng-hide/ng-show on a boolean method indicating whether your user is logged in?

Comment: I have not, how would I get that boolean though? I don't know how to change the values that the Directive has to work with.